# fullcalendar format dayGrid day cell to show month and day

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I want to show the day of each cell as the "month day" I've already try to use slotLabelFormat, and all the others slotLabel, but any of those worked.
The picture below is how I did using JS, but when I perform any action on the calendar, it got a refresh and render the default, which is only the day[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show us your code.

Answer (score 2):

Solved!
I added the dayRender method like this:

```
dayRender(eventInfo){
 if(eventInfo.view.type === 'dayGridMonth'){
  return eventInfo.el.innerHTML = moment(eventInfo.el.dataset.date, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('MMM DD');
 }
}
```

and this on my CSS

```
.fc-day-number{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: If you are using version 5, dayRender has been deprecated in favour of 4 other properties (dayCellClassNames, dayCellContent, dayCellDidMount, dayCellWillUnmount). More info in the upgrade notes: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v4

Answer (score 1):

There is a page on how to customize with your own Javascript:

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js

Specifically, there is

`renderDates(dateProfile) {
    // responsible for rendering the given dates
  }`

and more steps on how to accomplish a more customized view. Hope this helps!

Comment: This is true, but creating a whole custom view is massively overkill for the simple adjustment the OP wants to make. It can be done by simply hooking into the dayRender callback, enabling a small change to be made to the existing view.